# Unable to run linux commands from exec Java method

Tags: java, linux, exec

I am trying to execute cf commands from Java exec method instead of typing from the linux terminal manually. I pass the exact syntax what i do from the terminal However i get error when passing the first argument to the method because it contains spaces I am not sure how to debug it ?

From Linux terminal directly

```
root@devopsops:/home/Data/free# cf create-service 'IBM Analytics for Hadoop' Free 'IBM_Analytics_for_Hadoop'_APP
Creating service IBM_Analytics_for_Hadoop_APP in org All_Testing / space monitor-ms1 as xyz@gmail.com...
OK
```

...

If i run the same command from exec method in java i get the following error

```
cf create-service 'IBM Analytics for Hadoop' Free 'IBM_Analytics_for_Hadoop'_APP
Here is the standard output of the command:

FAILED
Incorrect Usage.

NAME:
   create-service - Create a service instance

ALIAS:
   cs

USAGE:
   cf create-service SERVICE PLAN SERVICE_INSTANCE
```

Java code

Main method

```
obj.cfCreateService("'IBM Analytics for Hadoop'","Free");
```

cfCreateService method

```
public String cfCreateService(String servicename, String planname){

        String s = null;
        StringBuffer log = new StringBuffer("");

        try {
            String appname= servicename.replaceAll(" ", "_")+"_APP";
            String command="cf create-service "+servicename+" "+ planname +" "+ appname; 
            System.out.println(command);
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                 InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                 InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            // read the output from the command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
                log.append(s+"\n");

            }


        }


    }
```

Comment: Use ProcessBuilder, which is much better in handling command arguments

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing looks about right, but perhaps you could try enclosing the parameters into the array argument to exec():

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cf", "create-service", servicename, planname, appname});
```

instead of

```
        String command="cf create-service "+servicename+" "+ planname +" "+ appname; 
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```